# How can i get HTML element in a lightning component controller?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, html, error-messages

**Scenario:**

I'm saving a record in a modal popup, when the record is saved i need to check if there are any error added on the page.

The record is exposed using:

```
<force:recordEdit aura:id="editRecord" recordId="{!v.recordId}"/>
```

I should have used the Lightning:recordEditFrom but it's not supported by **Task** which is the objectType i'm working on

The record is saved using:

`component.find("editModal").get("e.recordSave").fire();`

**Solution:**

From the HTML inspector i've seen that the div containing the errors has a class called "genericError uiOutputText", so after the saving instruction i'm trying to catch them using:

```
var elements = document.getElementsByClassName("genericError uiOutputText");
console.log("elements.length: " + elements.length);
for (var i=0; i<elements.length; i++) {
    console.log(elements[i].innerHTML);
}
```

**Problem:**

Problem is `elements.length` comes always with 0 length.

Any other element on the page is correctly found, except for the errors.

I've tried executing these actions with a timeout but the outcome is the same.

I've tried executing the same JS code i'm using in the controller directly in the browser and the errors are **FOUND**. I really can't understand why these errors are not found from the controller but they are from the browser.

I think the problem is related to the dynamic creation of these errors but i really cant come out with an answer.

Does anyone know how to help on this?

Comment: Seems like you are asking [xy problem](http://xyproblem.info/), you probably should use [`lightning:recordEditForm`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:recordEditForm/documentation) as it provides more controls. With current implementation you will have problems with locker service or in case salesforce changes HTML structure or the classes `genericError uiOutputText`.

Comment: I can't use lightning:recordEditForm because i'm working on a Task Record which is not supported

Comment: i've really tried everything to get these errors, i'm trying to catch them from the DOM as last resource

Comment: you can create your own form and add `lightning:input` components then use `lightning:button` type submit, then you can catch the errors and show them